# find and print specific information with its name

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a list of data file 1 which I want to find in  file 2 where I want to grep the match pattern with its name. It is not necessary that each name consists of unique data. It may be common among names.

File 1:

```
123_A7
456_B2
789_f5
111_L2
```

main file:

```
A   Edwin
B   777
B   123_A7
B   456_B2
A   Alex
B   453
B   678
A   Marwin
B   789
B   123_A7
B   111_L2
B   452
```

Desired Output:

```
B   123_A7
A   Edwin
A   Marwin
B   456_B2
A   Edwin
B   111_L2
A   Marwin
```

Comment: Are you sure line 5 of your output shouldn't read `A  Edwin` instead?

Comment: @Philippos yes I have corrected it Thankyou

Comment: can you please clarify how and why the lines containing `A Edwin` and `A Marwin` should be present in the output.

Comment: Your pattern matching description doesn't explain how the patterns in file 1 would match `Edwin` or `Marvin`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Philippos I reverted your edit since we do not know if this is really the reasoning the OP intended (although it seems logical and may be true)

Comment: @Wayne_Yux I Interpreted his description and found an error in the desired output. The OP confirmed my correction so I'm awfully sure about that. On the other hand, if he's still interested, he can return to my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/\s/{H;d;}
  G;s/\nB/#B/g
  s/^\(.*\)\(\n\n.*#\)\(B\s*\1\)/\3#\2\3/
  /^[^#]*\n/d
  :a;s/^\([^#]*\)\(#.*\n\)\(A[^#]*\)\([^\n]*#\)\1/\1#\3\2/;ta
  s/#\n.*//;y/#/\n/' main file1
```

First read the `main` file to collect the codes for each name in the hold space (line 1). Then for each line of `file1` append the hold space, replace newlines before `B` lines with `#` for easier parsing (line 2) and search with backreferences for matching codes (line 3). Delete lines without matches (line 4). Now loop to collect the names for the given pattern (line 5). Finally print with the remaining hold space removed and `#` converted back to newlines (line 6). (Note: works with GNU `sed` only)

Comment: Very impressive, but wouldn't that be simpler with `awk`?

Comment: I dropped `awk` for `perl` long ago. Nowadays I do complex tasks in `python` and the rest in `sed`, no room left for `awk`. This one maybe would be easier to maintain in `python`. But you can suggest an `awk` version.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1];next} /^A/{NAME=$0}
    {for (x in seen){ if ($2==x)print $0"\n"NAME}}' file1 main
```

The output is:

```
B   123_A7
A   Edwin
B   456_B2
A   Edwin
B   123_A7
A   Marwin
B   111_L2
A   Marwin
```

Above is printing IDs and Name if its inherit of that ID but in separate. Here is the complete script to group Names where they are in same IDs.

```
awk -F'\t' '{a[$1]=a[$1]"\n"$2} END{for (i in a) print i""a[i]}' <(
    awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1];next} 
        /^A/{NAME=$0}{for (x in seen){ if ($2==x)print $0"\t"NAME}
    }' file1 main)
```

The output is:

```
B   111_L2
A   Marwin
B   456_B2
A   Edwin
B   123_A7
A   Edwin
A   Marwin
```

Comment: @derHugo in this case the syntax highlighting is useless, since all of the awk code is inside a string.